# Non existing instructor

Tags: teaching, transfer-student, course-evaluation

I'm wondering if I am able to possibly have a lawsuit against the trade school I go to because they haven't provided us with an instructor for the last couple of months. I've gone to the campus numerous times to talk to whoever is in charge and they keep saying they're trying to fix it BUT I'm paying out of pocket for my tuition and need answers to what is possible and not possible????

Comment: This would probably be more on-topic at https://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's also important that you indicate the country and/or state you are located in.

Comment: What would you like them to do? "Provide an instructor" is not necessarily something they can wave a magic wand to make happen; "give a refund" might be more practical. If you need legal advice, though, neither this site nor Law is going to do that for you, you need to ask a lawyer.

Comment: Is this a problem with just one course of many or the entire program?

Comment: It's just our one course.